# How to use __str__ to print the stored data in a dictionary

Tags: python

How do I use the `__str__` to print the dictionary stored data whenever I give the `print` command. I am using:

```
def __str__(self):
    for atom in self.pdb_atoms().keys():
        return '%s'%self.pdb_atoms()[atom]
```

If I have a dictionary in python whose index has a string and a integer like `{ 'CA' 56: 'ATOM 727 HG2 57 -7.010000 11.418000 -23.532000'....}`

But this gives me data corresponding to a single key instead of the whole list; this prints only line 727 from a list of 1344 lines. I have no clue, where I am going wrong. `pdb_atoms` is the name of the dictionary

Comment: If `pdb_atoms` is indeed a dictionary, you should be getting an error message about it not being callable, not a single element.

Comment: I assumed it was a command returning a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

What do you think it could mean to have `return` in a loop? `__str__` has to return a string. If your function worked as you expected, it would have returned one string for each atom... then what? How is Python supposed to know how to combine those into one string without you telling it? There are *many* ways of gluing strings together, and that's not even a very likely way top interpret a function returning multiple times (what if it returned numbers?).

In fact though, functions can only return once, and this is a fundamental property of almost every language I can think of (except for logic programming languages). So all that happens if you put `return` in a loop is that the function returns on the first iteration of the loop and is done. This is exactly why your function only shows you the first key!

There is something a bit like `return` that can be used more than once: `yield`. Effectively this allows you to return multiple values as an iterator (which you can loop over **once only** with a `for` loop to get them back again). But that doesn't help you here because `__str__` should return a string, and an iterator containing multiple strings is not a string!

Answer (score 0):

You see the problem because you are returning from your function call before constructing your entire list. Try the following to return your entire dictionary:

```
def __str__(self):
    return ''.join([self.pdb_atoms()[atom] for atom in self.pdb_atoms().keys()])
```

Also, note how you can directly use the string object without having to do `'%s'%(string)`

Edit:
As @Wooble pointed out in the comment, you can not call a dictionary object. I assume that what you mean by pdb_atoms is a command that returns a dictionary. If not, please remove the `()`.

Comment: def __str__(self):
    return '%s'%self.pdb_atoms()[atom] for atom in self._pdb_atoms.keys() says invalid syntax pointing at "for"

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: And secondly, why did you use `return '%s'%`

Comment: Ahh sorry, my bad, forgot to join the list of values. As @Enrico rightly points out, use join. See my edited post

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string with all the values separated by a newline try something like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(self.pdb_atoms())
```

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, instance found

Comment: `'\n'.join(map(str, self.pdb_atoms()))`

Comment: ... do be aware, this returns the *keys*, not the values

Answer (score 0):

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join(str(v) for v in self.pdb_atoms().itervalues())
```